# Making a listview sortable when it doesn't contain a layouttemplate and built in codebehind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview

I have a page of checkboxes, I select a few of them, click submit, and go to a second page.  on this page, I have a listview that is built using the checkboxes selected on the previous page.  Now I'm wondering how i can add sortability to this listview.

In the past I would add CommandName='sort' CommandArgument='column' to the link on the header in the LayoutTemplate.  But since my listview has it's header row outside of the listview, this doesn't seem to work. Any ideas on how I can implement this?  This is what I have so far:

```
<!-- header row (outside of listview, when I try to put it as a LayoutTemplate in listview i get an error, see below) -->
<table>
  <tr><% For Each i As String In Request.Form
            If i.IndexOf("checkbox_") = 0 Then
                Response.Write("<th>" & i.Substring(Len("checkbox_")) & "</th>")
            End If
      Next %></tr>
</table>

<!-- Then the listview: -->
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ReportListView" DataSourceID="ReportListViewSDS">
  <ItemTemplate>
   <table>
       <tr>
           <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder" />
       </tr>
   </table>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Then in the code behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ' This works fine:
    ' Get the Request Vars that are checkboxes, and build the sql command.
    ' Run the sql command
    ' Databind()
End Sub

' while binding the data, build the itemPlaceholder, to contain the contents of what's returned in the sql:
Protected Sub ReportListView_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItemEventArgs) Handles ReportListView.ItemDataBound

    If (e.Item.ItemType = ListViewItemType.DataItem) Then
        Dim plc As PlaceHolder = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("itemPlaceHolder"), PlaceHolder)
        Dim di As Data.DataRowView = e.Item.DataItem()

        For Each c In di.Row.ItemArray
            Dim l As New Literal
            l.Text = String.Format("<td class='customreport'>{0}</td>", c.ToString)
            plc.Controls.Add(l)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

I've tried to add a templatelayout in the listview, but that gives me an error on the line that binds the data (listview.databind() ), i'm assuming because this isn't possible.

Any way to get a sortable header row on this listview?  Thanks in advance?  Newbie, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered handling the [ListView.Sorting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.sorting.aspx) event and then invoking the [ListView.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.sort.aspx) method to fire the event?

You can add your sorting logic within the Sorting event handler and then invoke the Sort method like so (possibly from a LinkButton Click event in your generated header).

```
ReportListView.Sort("COLUMN", SortDirection.Ascending);
```

---

**Edit**

Here is a simple example. I assume you are using a SqlDataSource based on the naming of your DataSourceID.

My example uses a SqlDataSource to select a column named Item from a table named Items and then display the data in the ListView.

I created a Button which performs a Sort on the ListView specifying the Item column and the sort direction.

**Markup**

```
<asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" Text="Sort" OnClick="button1_Click" />
<asp:ListView ID="listView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="sqlDataSource">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div><%# Eval("Item") %></div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=******;Integrated Security=SSPI;" SelectCommand="SELECT Item FROM Items">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Session["SortDirection"] = SortDirection.Ascending;
    }
}

protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SortDirection sortDirection = (SortDirection)Session["SortDirection"] == SortDirection.Ascending ? SortDirection.Descending : SortDirection.Ascending;
    Session["SortDirection"] = sortDirection;

    listView1.Sort("Item", sortDirection);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I did try that, but coudln't get it working.  Do you maybe have a working example, or more detail?  I checked the pages, and tried implementing the code exactly.  The problem is when I click on the linkbutton that is supposed to sort, the page just refreshes, the sorting isn't applied.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: I think the problem is that the Linkbuttons are not within the Listview. Since i'm adding the "CommandName"= Sort to linkbuttons that are outside of the listview, that's probably why they aren't having any effect.  Again, it comes back to not having the LayoutTemplate.  Since I have just created a table outside of the listview to act as my header table.